# How to get the data from all the subcollection from all the Users from firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have data something like Customer -> documnetid -> Orders(collection) same as for all customer.
I need to show the list of orders from all the customer in a list.
If a customer orders a item again it needs to create another list.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("customer")
        .doc('a44d4c1b-7faa-4139-b707-a40499fe4ce5')
        .collection("orders")
        .where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'ordered')
        .snapshots(),
```

I can get the data if I provide specific document id. But I need to get orders from all the customers.
Please help me in this.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should use a Collection Group query, as explained in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and in the [Dart `cloud_firestore` package documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html).

Something along these lines:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup("orders")
    .where('orderStatus', isEqualTo: 'ordered')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            //...
        });
    });
```

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error when I tried the method u suggested I got the records of all customer orders, suppose I have two customer and each have two orders I need to display 4 list of orders in a listview as seperate and also the customer name of that orders. If I added to list, when I give the length to itemCount as orders.length actually it should be 4 since there is 4 orders but it counts all of the data.
How can I display in a StreamBuilder his orders and his name together?

Comment: length is 4, but it shows 7, how? Would you please help me sir?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your data structure. Like you can create a new different separate collection for orders with the same fields + customer id field.

so you can get all orders and orders by customer id

So if you want to get an orders for a particular customer you can get by this :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("orders")
    .where('customerId', isEqualTo: 'a44d4c1b-7faa-4139-b707-a40499fe4ce5')
    .snapshots(),
```

And you can get all orders like this:

```
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("orders")
    .snapshots(),
```

OR if you still want to do it by your data structure you can do it by loop

```
List orders = [];
          
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('customer')
              .get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
              dynamic data = doc.data();
              orders.addAll(data['orders'] as List);
            });
          });
```

Comment: Thank you, but the orders collection is inside customer collection how can I loop over all the orders of different customers and get the data where orderstatus isEqual to ordered.

Comment: I have edited the answer to your concern please check if it helps you. @Jagan

Comment: @Jagan My answer answers to your above question/comment: "The orders collection is inside customer collection how can I loop over all the orders of different customers and get the data where orderstatus isEqual to ordered."